# pass parameter from jenkins parameterized build to windows batch command

Tags: batch-file, jenkins, cmd

I am starting to use Jenkins, which is a really great tool. We are using parameterized build, we define parameter such as branch name ${Branch} (e.g. dev, release, main etc).

In the build config, I can add a windows batch command, is there a way I can pass down these parameters to the batch command?

I tried to pass like "%${Branch}%" or "%Branch%", but seems not working.

Can anyone help?

Many Thanks

Comment: What this have to do with TFS?

Comment: @GiulioVian tags have been updated. :)

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Using **Parameterized Build**, you need to define parameters. The value of these will be prompted to you when you click "Build" link.

The name of the parameters should be a **plain name**, preferably without spaces, like `Branch`. Do not add any `${}` or `%%` to definition of the parameter name.

In the **build steps**, like **Execute Windows Batch Command**, you can reference the parameter with regular batch syntax, like `%Branch%`.

If you would be on a *nix machine, you would use **Execute shell** build step and reference the parameter with regular bash syntax, like `${Branch}`

Note that even when running on Windows, a lot of Jenkins plugins themselves take the parameters in *nix syntax, however the **Execute Windows Batch Command** will be batch-like, i.e. `%Branch%`.

So, you can try typing:
`echo %Branch%`

I also suggest putting just `set` command on a line by itself, and it will show you all environment variables available to you during the build process, which is quite useful.

Comment: @UnderDog you can override the parameter, but the next build step ("outside of windows batch command") starts off with a **clean** environment inherited from the job, therefore your modifications are lost. This is by design to keep the build system clean. You can use **[EnvInject plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin)** for all sorts of environment variable manipulation, including what you need.

Comment: Thnks.. Really help me.

Comment: I was looking to run the cypress tests in Jenkins using choice parameters. Using the above the solution I did this: npm run %scripts%. where "scripts" is the name of choice parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I do not really get exactly what you mean branches because I am a bit new, but this worked for me if you are talking about how to do like yourcmd -a and have it run different code then the original and -b.
In the dir, create two files with your parameter names
eg
-a.bat
-b.bat
You do not need to write any code in those.
In the code for your command
eg createfolder.bat
Write

```
@echo off
if %~n1 == -a goto :aran
if %~n1 == -b goto :bran
:aran
Your first parameter code
cls
:bran
Your 2nd parameter code
cls
```

Hope it helped!
You can even add up to 50 parameters!