# Using Jenkins job parameter in a bat command

Tags: jenkins

I'm trying to configure a parameter in Jenkins pipeline and then execute it within bat command:

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        label 'master'
    }
    parameters {
        string (
            defaultValue: '"someExe.exe"',
            description: '',
            name : 'varExe'
        )
    }
    stages {
        stage("hi") {
            steps {
                script {
                    bat '${params.varExe}'
                }
            }
        }       
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, i'm getting this error:

```
'${varExe}'is not recognized as an internal or external command
```

For some reason, Jenkins doesn't use `varExe` value.

I've also tried `bat '${varExe}'` but still no luck.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use a double quote here to replace the variable.

```
bat "${params.varExe}"
```

You have to be careful with single and double quotes. For the following example, the first one would echo someExe.exe, while the second one would throw a Bad substitution error.

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    parameters {
        string (
            defaultValue: '"someExe.exe"',
            description: '',
            name : 'varExe')
    }
    stages {
        stage ('Test') {
            steps {
                script {
                    sh "echo '${params.varExe}'"
                    sh 'echo "${params.varExe}"'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think for bat command should be like below

```
bat ''' echo %varExe% '''
```

reference : [pass parameter from jenkins parameterized build to windows batch command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24429976/pass-parameter-from-jenkins-parameterized-build-to-windows-batch-command)