# How to insert variable to sh aws command in a jenkins pipeline groovy script?

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, groovy, command-line-interface, amazon-ecr

How can I pass the variables into the below sh command? This is as part of the jenkins pipeline groovy script I am using:

Working as it as when I use the values directly as below. I.e with "test" and :us-west-2"

```
sh '''
$(aws --profile test ecr get-login --no-include-email --region us-west-2)
'''
```

Not working when I try to parameterise with profile and region as below:

```
sh '''
$(aws --profile "${params.profile}", ecr get-login --no-include-email --region "${params.region}")
'''
```

ERROR:

```
[Pipeline] sh
/opt/slave_home/workspace/test1@tmp/durable-de1d1e87/script.sh: 2: /opt/slave_home/workspace/test1@tmp/durable-de1d1e87/script.sh: Bad substitution
+
```

Comment: You need to double quote the sh command - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52307739/using-jenkins-job-parameter-in-a-bat-command/52308003#52308003

Answer (score 0):

Working with the following syntax:
sh '''
(`aws --profile "${profile}" ecr get-login --no-include-email --region "${region}"`)
'''