# Jenkins Pipeline: Param in batch call

Tags: jenkins

I have a pipeline build working in Jenkins, and have made the project parameterized to pass some information into the pipeline script.  Everything works well except for inserting a "String Parameter" into a call to a batch file.

```
string(name: 'SANDBOX_ID', defaultValue: 'Build', description: 'Build Identifier (BuildNNN)')
```

I can see the parameter added, and can populate it via "Build with Parameters".  I tried using it like so:

```
steps {
    bat 'FtpPublisher.exe -srcDir "%WORKSPACE%/Builds/WebGL/Build" -targetDir "/Builds/${params.SANDBOX_ID}"'
}
```

This always results in a new folder created on my FTP server with the name "${params.SANDBOX_ID}" instead of the actual SANDBOX_ID parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found answer here after some more searching: [pass parameter from jenkins parameterized build to windows batch command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24429976/pass-parameter-from-jenkins-parameterized-build-to-windows-batch-command)

Fixed by using %SANDBOX_ID% instead of ${params.SANDBOX_ID}